# XML from Webservice syntaxerror jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services, xml-parsing, webserver, syntax-error

I have to read a XML request from a server.
If I save the XML locally, everything is working fine.

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1410/?SNO=56789&ASQL=plu%20mec%2010;',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find('dataset').each(function () {
        $("#output").append($(this).find('var[key="article.name"]').text() + "<br />");
    });
}
```

**XML Output:**

```
<document name="screen">
  <section name="status">
    <dataset>
      <var key="organization.number">2919</var>
      <var key="organization.name">Testname</var>
      <var key="organization.businessdate">09.02.2013</var>
      <var key="situation.number">0</var>
      <var key="situation.name">Normalbetrieb</var>
      <var key="site.number">0</var>
      <var key="site.name">Normalbetrieb</var>
      <var key="pricelevel.number">1</var>
      <var key="pricelevel.name">Standardpreis</var>
      <var key="terminal.number">0</var>
      <var key="terminal.name">WebKasse</var>
      <var key="terminal.status">open</var>
      <var key="terminal.tapster">inactive</var>
      <var key="waiter.number">1</var>
      <var key="waiter.name">Kellner 1</var>
      <var key="table.number">5</var>
      <var key="table.balance">3.2</var>
      <var key="table.sales">3.2</var>
      <var key="profile.number">1</var>
      <var key="profile.name">Standard</var>
      <var key="execution.severity">I</var>
      <var key="execution.code">23600003</var>
      <var key="execution.message">Mec article list.</var>
    </dataset>
  </section>
  <section name="plu.list">
    <dataset>
      <var key="type">article</var>
      <var key="article.number">1</var>
      <var key="article.name">0,1 l Becher Sekt</var>
      <var key="article.displayname"/>
      <var key="article.price">3.7</var>
      <var key="article.plunumber">1</var>
      <action key="STANDARD">book plu 1;</action>
    </dataset>
    [...]
```

**With this code my page is blank and shows this error:**

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

<document name="screen"><section name="status"><dataset><var[...]
```

The strange thing: I can see the XML output *in the error*!

If I change the `data type:` to `xml`

No error, page blank.

Comment: http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/9229/synerr.png If i click on the error, i can see the hole xml file ?!

Answer (score 0):

You should use dataType: xml, because you are expecting to get xml response.
If you have different results with different web servers, check 
the MIME type of the response.

I think that the problem is wrong MIME type.

Or you can get the response as String, and parse it as xml with jQuery

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "title" );
```

Comment: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 "parse it as xml..." I have no idea how to do that